# what's the meaning of green circle with 'a' in front of prompting in this pic?

Tags: eclipse

when i used alt + '/' in eclipse ,i don't understand the symbol and the char a in front of method name . 
example : ·A add(String e) : boolean - Colletion
          ·D foreach(...) : void
what the ·A or ·D mean?

[image: symbol and the char a in front of prompting]

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that this is an abtract ("A") public method (green circle). The "D" indicates a default method.

You can see what all the Eclipse symbols mean [here](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm).